# bash script using sed command on remote server with ssh and special characters

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to run this sed command on a remote server through a bash script but I can not get the escaping correct.

```
ssh -t user@ip "sed -i -e '/<!--insert_new_code-->/i\          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">\n            <?php include "''explorers/'"${coin_symbol_lower}"'.php''";?>\n          </div>\n\n' /home/some-data/some_dir/dir/dir/index.php"
```

I have the spaces in there to keep the html code looking clean. The sed command works fine when ran locally, just not over ssh.

Any help getting it working would be appreciated

Comment: Please do mention if you got any error messages while running it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command passed to `ssh` is delimited by double quotes. Since there are also double quotes within the string being passed to `sed`, they will need to be escaped to prevent the shell from trying to take them:

```
    ssh -t user@ip "sed -i -e '/<!--insert_new_code-->/i\          <div class=\"col-lg-4 col-md-6\">\n            <?php include \"''explorers/'\"${coin_symbol_lower}\"'.php''\";?>\n          </div>\n\n' /home/some-data/some_dir/dir/dir/index.php"
```

Comment: Thank you! I also had to escape the ! but after that this worked

Answer (score -1):

Try this syntax

```
ssh -t user@ip << \EOF
sed -i -e '/<!--insert_new_code-->/i\          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">\n            <?php include "''explorers/'"${coin_symbol_lower}"'.php''";?>\n          </div>\n\n' /home/some-data/some_dir/dir/dir/index.php
EOF
```